# Copy google doc spreadsheet using php api

Tags: php, excel, copy, google-docs, google-api-php-client

I want to copy Google Doc spreadsheet file.This [code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) I am using

```
function copyFile($service, $originFileId, $copyTitle) {
  $copiedFile = new Google_DriveFile();
  $copiedFile->setTitle($copyTitle);
  try {
    return $service->files->copy($originFileId, $copiedFile);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return NULL;
}


require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('myclientid');
$client->setClientSecret('myclient secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);



copyFile($service,'my schema id','Copy Of Schema');
```

I am not able to get $service instance. SO I searched and get the above way to do but now it is giving 401 login required error.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for sufficient authorization from the user

1. you need to generate authorization URL:

> $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

2. Redirect user to the authUrl
3. Make user paste the authorization code:

> ```
> $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
> ```

4. Authenticate

> $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
>
> $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

5. Once above it done, you have now authenticated the user with OAuth to access drive.

Reference: [Click here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php)